# MVC Radio Button Always pass False Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the code for the `RadioButton` I have used:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.A, new { @class = "radio-inline", @checked = "checked", id = "A" }, "Indicator")
@Html.Label("Active")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.A, new { @class = "radio-inline", @checked = "checked", id = "B" }, "Indicator")
@Html.Label("InActive")
```

This Is Modal

```
private bool a;
public bool A
{
    get
    {
       return a;
    }    
    set
    {
       a= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your model? And you have not given the radio buttons a value so they do not post anything (and look at the html your code generates)

Comment: in both cases you use model => model.A

Comment: got some error with id :(

Comment: Fixed! Thank you Both,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `RadioButtonFor()` is the value, and the 3rd is the `htmlAttributes` so you code is generating

```
<input length="9" id="A" name="A" type="radio" value="{ class = radio-inline, checked = checked, id = A }" />
```

The `value` attribute is needs to be `true` or `false` in order to bind to a `bool` (and note the invalid `length="9"` attribute is because there are 9 characters in "Indicator").

In addition, do not attempt to set the `checked` attribute - the method sets that correctly based on the value of the property. And your creating a `<label>` element that has no relationship to the buttons (clicking on them will set focus).

Your code needs to be

```cs
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.A, true, new { @class = "radio-inline", id="" })
    <span>Active</span>
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.A, false, new { @class = "radio-inline", id="" })
    <span>InActive</span>
</label>
```

You can also simplify your model to use just

```cs
public bool A { get; set; }
```